# how to change sequence of key position in array of Object by passing key

Tags: arrays, angular, typescript, object

I am working on export functionality. but data coming from API is not in the required sequence (keys of the object in an Array). So I wanted to change this sequence of keys in object for a single row.
data is like this

```
data = [
{
  "key4":"value4",
  "key1":"value1",
  "key5":"value5",
  "key3":"value3",
  "key2":"value2"
},
{
  "key4":"value4",
  "key1":"value1",
  "key5":"value5",
  "key3":"value3",
  "key2":"value2"
}
]
```

And I want output like this

```
 data =[ {
  "key1":"value1",
  "key2":"value2",
  "key3":"value3",
  "key4":"value4",
  "key5":"value5"
 },
 {
  "key1":"value1",
  "key2":"value2",
  "key3":"value3",
  "key4":"value4",
  "key5":"value5"
 }
 ]
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Sort JavaScript object by key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5467129/sort-javascript-object-by-key)

Answer (score 1):

You could use `.map` with `Object.entries` and `Object.fromEntries`, and sort on the key:

```js
data = [
{
  "key4":"value4",
  "key1":"value1",
  "key5":"value5",
  "key3":"value3",
  "key2":"value2"
},
{
  "key4":"value4",
  "key1":"value1",
  "key5":"value5",
  "key3":"value3",
  "key2":"value2"
}
].map((item) =>
    Object.fromEntries(
        Object.entries(item).sort(
            (a, b) => a[0].localeCompare(b[0])
        )
    )
)

console.log(data);
```

Comment: thanks for your answer.I want to sort by passing the key name to the function, can you suggest how to do this

Comment: above code only sort by alphabetically so not able to use this

Answer (score 1):

I solved this by using the following code in angular.

```
let headerList = ["key1", "key2", "key3", "key4", "key5"]
let newExportData = [];

  data.forEach(obj => {
    let json = {};
    headerList.forEach(header => {
    json[header] = obj[header];
  });
  newExportData.push(json);
});
console.log(newExportData);
```